# Values are not displaying at run time but they are displaying at debugging time on console

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying out to click on menu link and execute a script which print all menu list. The output of this file is not printed to console when run java code directly but is printed when I step through in debug mode and my test script always display passed.

## HomePage.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindAll;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.freecrm.qa.base.BasePage;
import com.freecrm.qa.utils.TestUtil;

public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='user-display']")
    WebElement userdisplay;

    @FindAll({@FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='item-text']")})
    List<WebElement> menulist;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Calendar']")
    WebElement calanderlink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Contacts']")
    WebElement contactslink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Companies']")
    WebElement companylink;

    public HomePage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public boolean isUserDisplayed()
    {
        userdisplay.getText();
        return true;
    }

    public String  getLoggedUser()

    {
        System.out.println(TestUtil.getMsgText(30, driver, userdisplay));
        return  TestUtil.getMsgText(30, driver, userdisplay);
    }
    public void getAllMenu()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<menulist.size();i++)
        {

             System.out.println(menulist.get(i).getText());
        }

    }

    public void clickMenuLink(String menulink)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<menulist.size();i++)
        {

             //System.out.println(menulist.get(i).getText());
             if(menulist.get(i).getText().equals(menulink))
             {
                 menulist.get(i).click();
             }
        }

        }




    public ContactsPage clickContactLink()
    { 
        contactslink.click();
        return new ContactsPage();

    }



}
```

## HomeTest.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.freecrm.qa.base.BasePage;
import com.freecrm.qa.pages.ContactsPage;
import com.freecrm.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.freecrm.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class HomeTest extends BasePage {

    LoginPage loginpage;
    HomePage homepage;
    ContactsPage contactpage;

    public HomeTest()
    {
        super();

    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {

        initialization();
        loginpage=new LoginPage();
        loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"),prop.getProperty("password"));
        homepage=new HomePage();

    }

    @Test
    public void displayMenuList()
    {
        homepage.getAllMenu();

    }
    @Test
    public void clickContactLink()
    {
        homepage.clickMenuLink(prop.getProperty("menuName"));

        //return ContactsPage();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tear()
    {
        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I have already tried to increase buffer size of console but it is not working for me.

Comment: How are you running your Java code directly?

Comment: I am using testng .So, i am running only my testng xml file to run the script.

Comment: try adding a sleep

Comment: I added some sleep but it's not working